# Show multiple drupal 7 'name field' in one view row?

Tags: views

Using this on D7: https://www.drupal.org/project/name

The name field is on a 'book' content type. 1-to-many authors.

In views, I want to see the name of the book, and the authors. Currently, it shows one repeat row per author. How do I consolidate them into one row? The field setting does not seem to include anything for this.

Thanks, sorry if this is noob of the century territory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views aggregator plus module solved my problem https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator